# Why is $x^{-1}$ same as $1/x$?

Tags: exponential-function

Can someone explain to me why $x$ to negative $1$, i.e. $x^{-1}$, becomes $1$ over $x$? I asked all my teachers who just said it’s the law. I don’t understand it.

Please explain for a complete mathphobe/math illiterate.

Comment: Do you understand the convention $x^2=x*x$ or $x^3=x*x*x$, where $*$ means multiplication?

Comment: [Check this video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/cc-eighth-grade-math/cc-8th-numbers-operations/cc-8th-pos-neg-exponents/v/negative-exponents)

Answer (score 6):

Exponentiation follows the law

$$x^mx^n = x^{m+n}$$

If you use $m=1$ and $n=-1$

you get

$$x^1x^{-1} = x^0$$

So it follows that

$$xx^{-1} = 1$$

and

$$x^{-1} = \frac{1}{x}$$